# Setting up a sharepoint site for remote connection

Tags: sharepoint

I have been tasked with setting up a SharePoint 2013 site being a straight MVC developer has me scrambling to figure out how to implement a solution that works for everyone involved.

We have a server with SharePoint on it and visual stuido however RDC only has 2 connections (company will not pay for more connections, tried that route) and we have the potential for 8 developers to be logged in at once.

our local machine setup is windows 8.1 with visual studio 2013 on it.

I read somewhere you can do remote connections to SharePoint but have no clue how to set that up or if it's even possible for use.

if anyone can help point me in a direction that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you are strictly developing Apps you can develop remotely and [this TechNet covers the step-by-step](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179923(v=office.15).aspx) for it (configure the server and infrastructure for Apps, create a developer site and give your Devs the required permissions).

If you want to develop components that use the server side Object model (Microsoft.SharePoint.dll) you MUST do so from a SharePoint server.

You can try to copy the DLL over to your dev machine, and you can successfully build. With this, though, you will lose many of Visual Studio's integrations and will not be able to deploy or debug from Visual Studio